# Take part of a sequence in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sequence

I am trying to partially consume a sequence in Kotlin, in order to split it up.

```
fun main() {
    val seq = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).asSequence()
    println(seq.take(4).toList().toString());
    println(seq.toList().toString())
}
```

This outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 90]
```

But what I am after, is this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 90]
```

Making the lists is for demonstration purposes only. As such, creating a list of the entire sequence and splitting the list is not the answer I am after.

Comment: not a elegant solution `seq.withIndex().groupBy({it.index < 4}) { it.value }.values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out we can use iterators for this:

```
fun main() {
    val seq = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).asSequence().iterator()
    println(seq.asSequence().take(4).toList().toString());
    println(seq.asSequence().toList().toString())
}
```

This way the sequences advance the inner iterator. If the sequence was originally obtained from an `Iterable`, as is the case above, we can simplify even further:

```
fun main() {
    val seq = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).iterator()
    println(seq.asSequence().take(4).toList().toString());
    println(seq.asSequence().toList().toString())
}
```

Comment: If you are already starting with a list/iterable, it is better to use partition function directly. Why create sequence

Comment: @sidgate Using lists for demonstration purposes. In reality I'm using an XML parser.

Answer (score 5):

There is `asSequence()` function for iterator, but it returns sequence that can be iterated only once. The point is to use the same iterator for each iteration.

```
// I don't know how to name the function...
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.asIteratorSequence(): Sequence<T> {
    val iterator = this.iterator()
    return Sequence { iterator }
}

fun main() {
    val seq = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).asIteratorSequence()

    println(seq.take(4).toList().toString()) // [0, 1, 2, 3]
    println(seq.toList().toString()) // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    println(seq.toList().toString()) // []
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create two subsequences from the original:

```
    val seq = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).asSequence()
    val firstCount = 4
    val first = seq.take(firstCount)
    val second = seq.drop(firstCount)

    println(first.toList())
    println(second.toList())
```